# Identifying a weird Texas tree

Tags: species-identification, trees

I recently saw this tree in Texas, with many bees on it. I think it attracts   bees. However it didn't have any specific smell, so I don't know why there were so many bees (they were bee for sure). I tried to identify the leaves but couldn't. Dear experts: could you please identify this tree?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you be a little more specific regarding where within Texas? It's a big state.. hah. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. It was in Mt Pleasant, TX 75455

Comment: an in-focus picture of the fruit/nut will help as will a picture of the whole tree. just from this it could be hickory or one of the  walnuts.

Comment: almost certainly not a hickory, walnut or other member of the juglandaceae family. No compound leaves for starters...

Answer (score -1):

That looks like a live oak covered with oak galls

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Your answer seems reasonable, but you are more likely to get a positive response if you explain why your identification is correct and specify the genus and species since "live oak" can refer to many species. Specifically, please edit your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. ——— You may also wish to take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 